# Multiple Peer React versions npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, version, peer-dependencies, react-canvas

I am working on a react-app. At the moment I have installed react@17.0.0 and I have some plugins which need this version of react. Now I wanted also to use react-canvas, which needs react@15.0.0.

The Warning after installing react-canvas is the following:
npm WARN react-canvas@1.3.0 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Is it possible to define multiple react versions or something like that? Because I can't downgrade react, because of the other plugins and canvas is only running with react version 15.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you have to wait for the plugin's upgrade to support higher version of react, 16.x, 17.x, then update the `peerDeps` to be `15 || 16 || 17`
But based on the [plugin status](https://github.com/Flipboard/react-canvas/issues), looks like this plugins is dead, no update any more.

So if it still works with react, good luck, you can ignore the warning...